# Optimization of a medieval city

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new quite new to Unity ( started like month or 2 ago ) and I'm doing a RPG game like Skyrim. I found an asset pack called Viking Village (official Unity asset, the free one) and I started building a small village. I have around 22 buildings and some other props near them. My problem is optimization of this place. FPS count drops really fast, number of branches is around 1500-3000 at max at the gate and number of tris is around 3-12M. I changed the grapihic setting to medium and some terrain options, but it still isnt enought for me, current size of the city is around 2/3 of what i planned and I am afraid it will be unplayable when I will finish this. Any advice how to optimaze it ?
Again, I am quite new so please try to explain this as simple as possible.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTy83.jpg) - Terrain settings 
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM57p.jpg) - Quality settings
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5ePW.jpg) - City

Comment: Hi, my I advice you to read up upon the [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) article. This is not a specific programming problem we can help you with. Having said so, try: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization. And a personal tip: Build your game with blocks first and swap them with detailed graphics later.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do.  First make sure all objects that don't move are set as static, set up occlusion culling, add light probes and reflection probes.  You can also change the lighting settings if they are set as real-time to mixed or baked.  Sometimes people also use LOD objects, but it doesn't seem like you would want to make lower poly models of the ones you found in the asset store.